# Adding numeric field to end of text string in annotations using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, annotation

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I carefully moved thousands of annotations for a network that just contain a feature's name. Now for a report map I need to append a numeric score to the end of each annotation.

Current: Parking Lot: 01

Updated: Parking Lot: 01 - (95)

Now, I know this is an incredibly easy process to update the TextString field, but no matter what I do I cannot get the display to update. I just joined a table to the annotation based on the text string and then used the field calculator to append the numeric value to the end of the text string.

So what I have is an annotation class where the attribute table is correct in The TextString column which shows the updated name, but the display still shows the old name. I've restarted ArcMap and even tried opening it on a coworker's copy of ArcGIS Pro.

Annotations are stored in a GeoDatabase

Comment: Try a brand new mxd then add your layers?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by just running the field calculator on the same field with the value as itself. Seems you just have to force it to update.

So basically !String!=!String!